# Image resize - maintain aspect ratio

Tags: java, resize, bufferedimage

How could I resize an image and still keep it's aspect ratio?

This is the method that I use :

```
private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage,
            int type) {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,
                type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();

        return resizedImage;
    }
```

The `type` variable :

```
BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
int type = original.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
                    : original.getType();
```

The problem is that some images are correctly resized but others lose their aspect ratio because of the IMG_WIDTH and IMG_HEIGHT.

Is there a way to get the original image dimensions and then apply some kind of proportion resize to maintain the aspect ratio of the resized image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you use `originalImage.getWidth()` and `originalImage.getHeight()`? Then you can easily calculate aspect ratio. Don't forget that int/int = int, so you need to do

```
double ratio = 1.0 * originalImage.getWidth() / originalImage.getHeight();

or 

double ratio = (double) originalImage.getWidth() / originalImage.getHeight();
```

Regarding the additional math, you can calculate

```
int height = (int) IMG_WIDTH/ratio;

int width = (int) IMG_HEIGHT*ratio;
```

Then see which one fits your needs better and resize to `(IMG_WIDTH, height)` or `(width, IMG_HEIGHT)`

Answer (score 1):

To get the image size, see [`getWidth()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getWidth%28%29)/[`getHeight()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getHeight%28%29).  The rest is just some relatively simple math.

Presuming the `IMG_WIDTH` & `IMG_HEIGHT` represent the largest size desired:

- Find which is going to hit the limit first.
- Calculate the ratio between the natural size and that maximum size.
- Multiply the other image dimension by the same ratio.

Comment: my question is there any issue with Image#getScaledInstance

Comment: @mKorbel Not sure if it still applies, but see [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html).